# Можно ли в диаграмме вариантов использования отражать внутреннюю работу системы?

Tags: uml

Можно ли в диаграмме вариантов использования отражать внутреннюю работу системы? А то есть, например, вариант использования `login`. Можно ли указывать в этом типе диаграммы - какие классы, программные модули или модели, имеющие к нему отношение, будут использованы при разработке.

Comment: Диаграммы использования применяются для проектирования, то есть, предположительно, на этапе их разработки до классов и программных модулей дело ещё не дошло. Т.е. сначала делаем диаграммы, потом смотрим на них, и проектируем код. Но задним числом, наверное, ссылки ставить можно. Я бы сказал, что обычно важнее стрелка в обратном направлении: вы смотрите над проектное решение (код) и хотите понять, почему принято именно такое. Тогда вам нужна ссылка из кода на диаграмму прецедентов. Такие ссылки формируются при помощи трекеров и систем контроля версий.

Comment: не нашел ничего об uml трекерах и как система контроля версий сможет обнаружить связь между кодом и диаграммой?

Comment: Мы это делаем на уровне соглашений внутри команды. Диаграмма прецедента это то, что очень близко к понятию *user story*. В Scrum мы описываем историю в трекере, как product backlog item, PBI. Затем мы создаем ветку в центральном репозитории git на основании этого PBI, если связка трекер/система версионирования это позволяет. Альтернатива — в каждом коммите ссылаться на номер PBI через #-нотацию. Если IDE поддерживает систему контроля версий, то можно по классу найти коммит, где он появился, а по коммиту — PBI. Если не поддерживает, то из командной строки. В VS2015 это пять нажатий мышью.

Comment: Да, саму диаграмму как вложение присоединять к PBI. Мы конкретно так не делаем, поскольку диаграммы прецедентов не используем, используем пользовательские истории. Но диаграммы взаимодействия иногда складываем.

Comment: понятно, просто я пытаюсь связать диаграмму использования с другими типами диаграмм (например с диаграммой классов).